# is there any Impact of Installed JRE on Dojo based application, in terms of performance?

Tags: performance, browser, dojo

I have an application based on DOJO, with some performance issues on some workstations, not all.

We are trying to find out reason but since the behavior is not consistent its really difficult to pin point the reason for performance issues.

There are machines on which the code just works fine at most times, but then there are machines that would have the issues of getting stuck.

Note: We do not have access to the client machines that are reporting issues.

So one of the things we are looking at is: Installed JRE on the machines.

Please let me know.

Also if you have any suggestions where else I could look, please suggest.

Thanks
Nick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you are running Dojo under Node.js, then in theory you would need some kind of browser or other JavaScript container to run a Dojo application. If we assume that this is a browser based application, then Dojo is running inside of the browser's JavaScript engine.

So it seems very unlikely that the JRE would be effecting the browser's performance, unless to you are also running Java applets in your application.

You might want to look at what could be slowing down these workstations in general.